# Beginner Java static scope error

Tags: java, static, scope

(For a beginner Java class) 
The assignment specifies that i only make one Scanner instance, and I need it in more than one method, so i declared it outside of main. I declare an array and try to equate it with a method call, initialCash(), like I would in Python. The problem is if I make the initialCash method static, I can't use Scanner. If initialCash() isn't static, Eclipse is kind enough to tell me that it "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method." (in the money = initialCash(); line)
 How do I get around this?

```
package proj1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] money = new int[4]; 
        money = initialCash();

    }   
    public int[] initialCash()
    {
        int[] initialMoney = new int[4];

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Ones: ");
            initialMoney[0] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Fives: ");
            initialMoney[1] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Tens: ");
            initialMoney[2] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Twenties: ");
            initialMoney[3] = scanner.nextInt();

            if((initialMoney[0]>=0)&&(initialMoney[1]>=0)&&(initialMoney[2]>=0)&&(initialMoney[3]>0))    
            {
                return initialMoney;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("One or more invalid denominations. Try again.");
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance of your class and invoke initialCash on that instance from main.

```
money = new Project1().initialCash();
```

Comment: @BrianRoach no problomo. my daily 200 reps have exceeded already . doesn't really matter .. hehe.. thanks thou .. :)

Comment: thanks much, i'm obviously still getting used to the whole object-oriented thing

Answer (score 0):

What PermGenError said would definitely work, or you could make both the initalCash() method and the scanner reference variable static.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

creates a new `Scanner` object each time you create an object of type `Project1`. Whereas if you had written it as

`static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

It would create a single `Scanner` instance for use by all classes that refer to this object. In your question you mentioned there has to be exactly one Scanner object, if so this is the way to go.

If you use

`money = new Project1().initialCash();`

you are creating a new `Project1` object as well as a new Scanner object, if you were to reuse the `Scanner` object by calling another function you cannot as it is tied to that specific instance of `Project1`, so I'd recommend you make it `static`, the same with the `initialCash` function, it is tied to that object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Scanner and the initialMoney method static. This should fix your problem.

```
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] money = new int[4];
    money = initialCash();

}
public static int[] initialCash()
{
    int[] initialMoney = new int[4];

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Ones: ");
        initialMoney[0] = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Fives: ");
        initialMoney[1] = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Tens: ");
        initialMoney[2] = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Twenties: ");
        initialMoney[3] = scanner.nextInt();

        if((initialMoney[0]>=0)&&(initialMoney[1]>=0)&&(initialMoney[2]>=0)&&(initialMoney[3]>0))
        {
            return initialMoney;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("One or more invalid denominations. Try again.");
        }
    }

}
```